# JVM snapshot for later debugging

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, dump, snapshot

Is there any way how to capture state of Java application (or whole JVM) for later debugging (alternative of core dumps for native executables)?

I know about heap dumps and thread dumps but these don't allow truly inspect the application state: get values of all available variables for all stack frames of all threads.

**Use case:** I use an app that crashes for some exception. Using snapshots I could attach a debugger to the app, set exception breakpoint and pause JVM in same interesting state, create a snapshot and send it to developer for inspection.

What I've found so far:

- [JSR 326: Post mortem JVM Diagnostics API](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=326)

  state: unfinished, dormant
- gcore + jsadebugd + jdb

  ```
  $ gcore <pid>
  Saved corefile core.<pid>
  $ jsadebugd /path/to/executable/java core.<pid>

  # from other terminal
  $ jdb -connect sun.jvm.hotspot.jdi.SADebugServerAttachingConnector:debugServerName=localhost
  ```

  This is almost it. However it can't be used with IDEs (like Eclipse or IDEA).

Comment: To get debug information, you have to run the program in debug mode.  To get the information you need, you have to connected to a running program, you can't just get a dump of this information.

Comment: What do you mean by "debug information"? I'm asking because coredump + jsadebugd + jdb provide stack frames of all threads, possibility to print values of fields and bindings to lines of source code.

Comment: "get values of all available variables for all stack frames of all threads." - actually heap dumps contains all this information. What else do you need?